# How to capture and store an image in django

Tags: django

I wanted to access the camera. capture an image and store in the database.

models.py :

```
class student(models.Model):   
    Img = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
```

HTML page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> webcam </title>
</head>
<body>
<div class = "video-wrap">
<video id = "video" playsinline autoplay></video>
</div>
<div class = "controller">
<button id = "snap">Capture</button>
</div>
<canvas id = "canvas" width = "640" height = "480">
</canvas>
<script>
'use strict';
const video = document.getElementById('video');
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const snap = document.getElementById('snap');
const errorMsgElement = document.getElementById('span#ErrorMsg');
const constraints = {
audio:true,
video:{
width:1280,height:720
}};
async function init()
{
try
{
const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
handleSuccess(stream);
}
catch(e)
{
errorMsgElement.innerHTML
=`navigator.getUserMedia.error:${e.toString()}`;
}
}
function handleSuccess(stream)
{
window.stream = stream;
video.srcObject = stream;
}
init();
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
snap.addEventListener("click",function(){
context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480);});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This HTML page can access the camera and can capture. But I don't know how to access and get that to models. can anyone pls help

Comment: Unless there is a specific reason why you want to manually code this yourself i'd suggest a service call Uploadcare - https://uploadcare.com/. you can easily embed their widget and it supports taking pictures from the webcam. see their django guide here- https://uploadcare.com/docs/guides/django/

Comment: did you implement it please ? now i faced the same challenge

Comment: @Mohan did you solve it please ?

Comment: I didn't solve that as I questioned. I changed to angular at front end and converted the image to base64 and that I stored in database using django. The model field is 
    photo =  Base64Field(max_length=900000, blank=True, null=True). The package needed for it is - from django_base64field.fields import Base64Field

Answer (score 0):

To capture images in Django you can make use of the python imaging library PILLOW(https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/). It is easy to use

Comment: I didn't understand how can I access image from html using pillow. Any code link. Kindly provide.

Answer (score 0):

you can use open cv module to capture an image. By using input type=submit and using form, and by defining open cv function in view file 
https://github.com/kevinam99/capturing-images-from-webcam-using-opencv-python

Comment: I had used open CV Module but Now I want to store that image in MySQlite that is connect via django. How can I acheive it?